# Shared element transition: Transition flickers because target fragment has a nested scroll view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-constraintlayout, shared-element-transition

I have an image view in the centre of fragment A, need to animate it to top of fragment B when fragment B is started. The problem is that shared element(image view) is inside a nested scroll view of fragments B's layout. The animation happens but it flickers and looks pretty bad.

view for fragment A:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivShared"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:transitionName="transition"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

view for fragment B:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivShared"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:transitionName="transition" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment B also has a recycler view inside the nested scroll view (omitted for brevity).
Open to other approaches too for making this animation work.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation on transitions with Recycler views](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/animate#recyclerview)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake tried the steps mentioned in the docs regarding postponing enter transition, but the animation still doesen't work properly